# Number between square brackets on FPGA schematic

Tags: fpga, schematics

I'm studying the schematics of an FPGA dev board. I have noticed that many pins have a number between square brackets. I attach a screenshot of a part of the schematics, with these number circled in green. Furthermore, on the right of the green circle, there is one pin with [2,5] before the name.

I would like to ask if you know what do they mean.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

If this is a multi-page schematic, those numbers could be the pages that the signal also appears on.

Answer (score 12):

Off-sheet, Page number reference